# how can I access to reactive formgroup validations?

Tags: angular

I want to validate my form field, but I have a formgroup inside it like this:

```
<form novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(user)" [formGroup]="user">
      <label>
        <span>Full name</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" formControlName="name">
      </label>
      <div class="error" *ngIf="!user.controls.name.valid && user.controls.name.touched">
        Name is required
      </div>
      <div formGroupName="account">
        <label>
          <span>Email address</span>
          <input type="email" placeholder="Email" formControlName="email">
        </label>
        <div
          class="error"
          *ngIf="!user.controls.address.email.valid">
          Email is required
        </div>
        <button type="submit" [disabled]="user.invalid">Sign up</button>
    </form>
```

but at email field it is not working this

```
!user.controls.address.email.valid
```

how can I get if that field is valid or not to show the message?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `user.controls.account.email.valid`? (`account` instead of `address`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try syntax like this:

```
user.get('account.email').valid
```

I have a complete example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-ReactiveForms This is code from my Pluralsight course: Angular 2: Reactive Forms.

Comment: Why was this voted down. Is this not the correct answer to this question?

Comment: This is very similar to what is in the docs: `<p>Street value: {{ heroForm.get('address.street').value}}</p>` at the reference here: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Answer (score 0):

Suppose my structure would be

```
 this.UserForm = this.fb.group({
            id: [this.userobj.id], 
            addresses: this.fb.group({
                street: [this.addrssobj.street, Validators.required],            
            })
});
```

My addresses.street validation would be like this (html)

```
<div formGroupName="addresses">
            <div>
                <label class="center-block"> Street: </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-group" formControlName="street" required>
                <div *ngIf="UserForm.get('addresses').get('street').hasError('required') && UserForm.get('addresses').get('street').touched" class="text-danger">
                    Street is required
                </div>
            </div>
```